# Uploading PFFile greater than 10mb

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

When I try to upload files greater than 10mb to my parse server, I get an error on the client side saying

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=263 "Failed to create PFFile at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/voice_message.mp4': file is larger than 10MB." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to create PFFile at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/voice_message.mp4': file is larger than 10MB.}
```

What's the best way of going about this? Should I split the file up into multiple PFFiles, upload that, and then restitch them on the server? Should I even use PFFile? Any advice would be super appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The PFFile 10MB limitation was removed in Parse iOS SDK (1.13.0). The Parse server has the limit of 20MB by default which can be removed too.

See: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/910